# Convolution support and property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I tried to answer a question from a user, as in the following link

[Properties of the solution of the schrodinger equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932690/properties-of-the-solution-of-the-schrodinger-equation)

As in the comments I am aware that my answer is not satisfactory, but intuitively it seems so.

In other words it is well known that if one of the two functions $f$ or $g$ has compact support, and we assume that it is well-defined convolution of them, then we have that

$$\mathrm{supp}(f \ast g) \subset \mathrm{supp}(f)+\mathrm{supp}(g)$$

My question is a reversal, that is, if $f$ has not compact support and $g$ has compact support, we may conclude that the convolution does not have compact support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. It is even possible that the convolution is identically zero. Consider $f(x) \equiv 1$, which clearly does not have compact support, and let $g(x)$ be any odd function with compact support. Then

$$(f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \, dy = 0.$$

Comment: I accept your answerm because it is proper to the question, as I have done. But basically I ask is another. If you are interested I asked here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250281/doubts-on-the-support-of-the-convolution-of-two-functions

Comment: I'm sure there are many special conditions you could place on $f$ and $g$ to make it true. Suppose for instance that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, and $g(x)\geq 0$ has compact support, but is not identically zero. Then $f*g$ cannot be compactly supported. I am thinking, as an example, of the solution of the heat equation $u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(x-y,t)g(y)\, dy$, where $S$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation.

Comment: By the way, you might get some flak for posting this type of question on MO, since it's not research-level, per se.

Comment: For as I asked the question here surely I receive criticism, but I asked the question in a slightly different way, and not have criticized me that much!